# I'm able to setAttribute() but not removeAttribute() in appEngine app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I recently discover a weird behavior with sessions, the title say everything.
Here's an example (it appears on every Servlets):

```
package com.orvif.servletsClient;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



/**
 * Servlet implementation class Accueil
 */
@WebServlet({"/Accueil","/"})
public class Accueil extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String view = "/WEB-INF/view_client/index.jsp";

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("test","test");
        System.out.println("Test before trying to remove : "+request.getSession().getAttribute("test"));
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("test");
        System.out.println("Test after remove operation : "+request.getSession().getAttribute("test"));

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(view).forward(request, response);
    }
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the line :

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("test");
```

Throws an NullPointerException and I honestly have no idea why. Here is what I can see on the console after calling the servlet :

```
Test before trying to remove : test
2018-10-16 15:59:44.444:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp1312381159-17: /favicon.ico
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppEngineSession.setAttribute(AppEngineSession.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.Session.removeAttribute(Session.java:786)
at com.orvif.servletsClient.Accueil.doGet(Accueil.java:37)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
at com.orvif.filters.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:123)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerRequestLogFilter.java:44)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.doScope(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Sessions are of course enabled in appengine-web.xml.
Here's appengine-web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <staging>
        <enable-jar-classes>true</enable-jar-classes>
    </staging>
    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

And web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MYAPP</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.orvif.config.InitilisationApp
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.orvif.filters.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Anyone could tell me what's happening here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste the complete doGet method. What you have now will not give you a NPE

Comment: What do you mean ? The doGet method is complete in the post. May be you mean the complete Servlet ?

Comment: What is the value of view?? `this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(view).forward(request, response);`

Comment: Ok so it was the complete Servlet. Just edited my post with what you asked. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error since yesterday and managed to fix it:
We used the Google Cloud SDK plugin in IntelliJ, and set it to manage the SDK installation itself. When setting it to use a local install everything seemed to work fine.
[image]

So: Are you using IntelliJ with the Google Cloud SDK for your project? If yes, that might be the problem in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It was the exactly the problem. Now it works fine !